# Error ' Invalid ZStream operation ' Delphi 11.0

Tags: delphi

I recently migrate to Delphi 11.0
this line  'Zip.CopyFrom(Source, 0); generate 'error 'Invalid ZStream operation'

```
uses system.ZLib;
...

    const
      ZLIB_GZIP_WINDOWBITS    = 31;
      ZLIB_DEFLATE_WINDOWBITS = 15;
    
    type
      TZLibCompressionLevel = TZCompressionLevel;

procedure ZLibCompressStream(Source, Dest: TStream; const Level: TZLibCompressionLevel;
        const GZipFormat: Boolean);
    var
      WindowBits: Integer;
      Zip: TZCompressionStream;
    begin
      if GZipFormat then
        WindowBits := ZLIB_GZIP_WINDOWBITS
      else
        WindowBits := ZLIB_DEFLATE_WINDOWBITS;
    
      Zip := TZCompressionStream.Create(Dest, Level, WindowBits);
      try
        Zip.CopyFrom(Source, 0);
      finally
        FreeAndNil(Zip);
      end;
    end;
    
    procedure TForm85.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    var s1,s2:TMemoryStream;
    begin
     s1:=TMemoryStream.Create;
     s1.LoadFromFile('h:\1.txt') ;
     s2:=TMemoryStream.Create;
     ZLibCompressStream(s1,s2,zcDefault,true);
    
    end;
```

on Delphi 10 and before no error occurs

Comment: May we assume that `1.txt` actually has a size larger than zero? If you look at `https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.Classes.TStream.CopyFrom` you will notice that Embarcadero might have changed code in there. Go check what the differences are. Also in the example; `https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Alexandria/en/ZLibCompressDecompress_(Delphi)` the compression part has a Count in `CopyFrom`. It might have worked previously with a `0` but the new changes might not

Comment: My file size is 5k and test with other file size and format but  no change happened on result .
I compiled this example

Comment: with Embarcadero® Delphi 11.0 Version 28.0.42600.6491 and rise same error  'Invalid ZStream operation'
Tstream.Copyfrom work fine with tmemorystream but for TZcompressionStream rise error.
I mention again, this code compile without any problem on Delphi 10.2
base a embarcadero note on 
' In version 11 the method has been optimized and now allows for better performance in case of a large Count.'
Couse this optimize routine not tested for TZcompressionStream by embarcadero staff and need release new  version

Comment: It is noticeable that the result output TZcompressionStream is correct on Delphi 10 and Delphi 11 and Can be Decompress without any error

Comment: Also update Delphi to 1.November can't solve this error and the problem exist.

Comment: I have the same problem. It was working on XE2 and throws an exception in XE11. VCL sources has changed. The call stack at the error is: TStream.CopyFrom(), TStream.GetSize(), TCompressionStream.Seek(0, soEnd). The latter causes the problem, since it supports only "(offset = 0) and (origin = soCurrent)". I guess, TCompressionStream should overload either CopyFrom() or GetSize().

Comment: "the result output TZcompressionStream is correct on Delphi 10 and Delphi 11" - There is  a comment in the TStream.CopyFrom() method that says, there might be exception "If Size/Position is not supported", and it is supressed. We got it in the debugger, and probably will not cause further problems, but makes debugging harder?

Comment: I had a similar issue when I tried to use TFDJsonDatasetsWriter. So I made a copy from the original System.Classes and modified the TStream.CopyFrom function that if the class name contains 'CompressionStream' I don't use the "new part" of the code. So far it works fine.

Comment: @Tamas: what is your modified code?

Comment: @A.K.D.: There is a try -except in the System.Classes between lines 9158 and 9172. 
I inserted before the try :
"if pos('CompressionStream', self.ClassName)<=0 then begin".
and after the
  try//original try-except
    ...
  except
  end;
I inserted this end: :-)
end;//if pos
I know it's not an elegant solution... but it works fine so far and I needed a quick solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be fixed in 11.1